# How to add unallocated space to encrypted partition (using Gparted)

Tags: partitioning, encryption, gparted

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I think I haven’t seen this exact situation on askubuntu yet.. I have an encrypted partition on a VPS running Ubuntu 18.04 that I would like to enlarge. I also have unallocated space. However, using Gparted I am unable to resize the partition. What can I do to solve this?

[image: Gparted]

[image]

Edit: resizing with [this method](https://blog.tinned-software.net/increase-the-size-of-a-luks-encrypted-partition/) almost works, except the last step.

I get:

```
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/mapper/vda5_crypt
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Anyone know what I could do about this?

Comment: I think you can't because you are working from the mounted `/dev/vda5` partition, is that correct? You need to reboot from a LiveUSB, and use `gparted` from there.

Comment: A Google search for “Gparted encrypted partition“ throws up many hits including the Gparted manual which contains instructions for working with LUKS: Select a closed LUKS encrypted partition. See the section called “Selecting a Partition”.

Choose: Partition → Open Encryption.

Comment: @Jos is it even possible to reboot from a LiveUSB with a VPS?

Comment: @PonJar When I select the encrypted partition and click on 'partition' in the menu, I don't see 'open encryption': https://www.dropbox.com/s/hu37lvbnqjcneli/Screenshot%202019-10-02%2013.40.02.png?dl=0

Comment: If that function is absent it suggests a version issue. What version of Gparted are you running? I think it will need to be 0.32 or above. The latest is 1.0.0-5.

Comment: Just checked "Open Encryption" exists in version 0.32

Comment: It is version 0.27. This is the Linux Rescue Mode from my VPS provider, so I'm afraid I won't be able to change this… https://www.dropbox.com/s/6y7992nhgqqkyoc/Screenshot%202019-10-03%2015.06.01.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enlarge the partition using the method outlined in [this forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726724).

I'll repost it here in case that post is taken down. Side note: I did not do steps 1 - 3, because I had already managed to enlarge the partition in Gparted.

1. Boot a live CD and, using any tool, create a new partition, lets call it /dev/sda6 , next to and to the left of (after) your crypt.
2. Write random data to the new partition.

Make sure you have the correct partition for this command or you will overwrite your crypt.

`sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda6`

You can run that command as many times as your paranoia requires.

3. Use fdisk as above to delete and then re-create a larger crypt partition.
4. Reboot to the live CD.
5. Install lvm2 and cryptsetup.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lvm2 cryptsetup`

6. Load the cryptsetup module.

`sudo modprobe dm-crypt`

7. Decrypt your file system.

`sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 crypt1`

8. Get the live CD to recognize (activate) your LVM.

`sudo vgscan --mknodes`
`sudo vgchange -ay`

9. Resize the Crypt.

`sudo cryptsetup resize crypt1`

10. Resize the (LVM) Physical volume.

`sudo pvresize /dev/mapper/crypt1`

11. Resize your root (LVM) Logical Volume.

Unlock the physical volume.

`sudo pvchange -x y /dev/mapper/crypt1`

Resize your root (LVM) Logical Volume.

`lvresize -L +4G /dev/hardy/root`

Note: Change the +4G to the amount of space you are adding.

Re-lock the (LVM) Physical Volume.

`sudo pvchange -x n /dev/mapper/crypt1`

12. Resize the filesystem.

`sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/hardy-root`
`sudo resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/hardy-root`